# How to solve firebase not working by changing package name already in connection with firebase?

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, dart, package-name

**- I have developed an app that is working properly with the default
package name (i.e. com.example.appname.**

- But As the Play Store would not allow an app with a default package
  name, it must be changed.
- So I have changed it throughout the app but you all know the
  connection with Firebase can be established using the app package
  name which creates a file( google.services.json).
- Hence By changing the package name, the app wouldn't be using
  Firebase services.

Desired Solution:
**How I can use Firebase services without recreating the whole project with a Firebase connection?**

Answer (score 2):

You will have to re-register your app on Firebase.

1. Go to the [Firebase console](https://console.firebase.google.com/).
2. Go to the project that has your app. (Choose the same project, so you have your data if any)
3. Click to Add app and then choose Android/Flutter. (You can delete your previous app once current app is registered)
4. Fill in your new package name and SHA details.
5. Download the new google-services.json file and replace it in your Android Project.

[image: Step 2]

[image: Step 1]

[image: Step 3]